# WinAPI timed mutex lock

Tags: c++, winapi, mutex, critical-section, timed

How to lock mutex (critical section) for some amount of time? Is there any API function for that? As far as I see there is nothing like that in windows. If so, is it possible to implement it manualy?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  You should always strive to lock mutexes for the shortest amount of time possible (otherwise you're blocking other threads unnecessarily).  Beyond that, unlocking a mutex before you're done with it will lead to horrible data corruption.

Comment: I'm talking about mutex lock timeout. Actually I'm interested in analogue of pthread_mutex_timedlock for windows.

Comment: If you're blocking on a mutex that's never available and timing out, why don't you just use Sleep()?

Comment: Just because you can not imagine a reason for somebody to do something, doesn't mean there isn't a good reason to do it. The fact that there exists a posix function pthread_mutex_timedlock() means somebody thought it was worthwhile to build into the pthreads library. And windows has an implementation as well, so there must be something to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of `pthread_mutex_timedlock()` in Win32 is using a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684266%28VS.85%29.aspx) and specifying a timeout (other than `INFINITE`) in one of the [wait-functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is the solution I'm looking for. Let me check and come back.

Comment: I believe this describes an overly complex Sleep() call.